# VMware Horizon Client not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: vmware

Which version of VMware horizon client works in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

I have tried latest version 5.4.1 and getting the following message,

```
sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-5.4.1-15988340.x64.bundle 
[sudo] password for balu: 
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Unable to load gtk: No module named gtk, falling back to console.
You must accept the VMware Horizon Client End User License Agreement
to continue.  Press Enter to proceed.
```

after installing VMware horizon client, I have tried to add server and hit enter after that VMWare horizon client window is closing. There after i didn't get any response.

Comment: it worked today perfectly.....the bad thing is...i'm not sure about the fix.
i will list the changes which i did in my Ubuntu 20.04 below before and after cases
**1. Installed Google Chrome Browser**-**Before installing Chrome**:When i run VMWare horizon and trying to addserver details and hit enter VMWare horizon application vanished away.
     **After installing Chrome** - When i try addserver and hit enter its redirecting and opening Chrome browser from there i got a prompt to open Horizon Client i will attach screen shot **2. Today there was a system update from Ubuntu**-This might help

Answer (score 3):

For me, installing `intel-media-driver-non-free` was the solution (at least on ubuntu 20.10). Disabling h.264 in the VMware Blast options also worked, but resulted in terrible image quality.

Comment: Disabling h.264 solved it also for me!

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem with VMware Horizon Client 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 and replacing `intel-media-va-driver` with `intel-media-va-driver-non-free` solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu 20.04 contains libffi.so.7. The missing libffi.so.6 fails launching the vmware client.

I made a symlink to solve this issue:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu $ ln -s libffi.so.7 libffi.so.6
```

Comment: after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 VMware horizon client stopped working. Creating the symlink solved the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `python2` for VMware horizon client to work:

```bsh
sudo apt install python
```

Reinstall VMware horizon client if it is still not working.

Answer (score -1):

1. Visit this VMware website link, and select the download button: https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/downloads/details?downloadGroup=CART21FQ2_LIN64_800&productId=1027&rPId=48990#product_downloads
2. The file to download is: VMware-Horizon-Client-2006-8.0.0-16522670.x64.bundle. Open the terminal, change directories with `cd` to the folder where the file was downloaded (e.g. `cd /home/$USER/Download` and run:

   ```
   sudo sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-x.x.x-yyyyyyy.arch.bundle
   ```