# Try to Uninstall VMware Horizon Client Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 20.04, vmware, 21.04

I am having trouble uninstall VMWare Horizon from my PC

I googled and found some commands to run on VMWare website:

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Linux/2012/horizon-client-linux-installation/GUID-9B5BE7D9-B4A9-4CBB-9534-7E65A813A751.html

According to website, I choose to run this command because I do not remember setting executable permissions on the installation file:

```
For uninstallation, if you have not set executable permission:

sudo env VMWARE_KEEP_CONFIG=yes \

sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-YYMM-x.x.x-yyyyyyy.arch.bundle -u vmware-horizon-client
```

I changed the syntax based on the version and build I have on my VMWare Horizon Client application:

```
@OMN:~$ sudo env VMWARE_KEEP_CONFIG=no \

sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-5.4.1-15988340.arch.bundle -u vmware-horizon-client
```

This is the output I got:

```
COLORTERM=truecolor
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
TERM=xterm-256color
DISPLAY=:1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
MAIL=/var/mail/root
LOGNAME=
USER=
HOME=/root
SHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env VMWARE_KEEP_CONFIG=yes
SUDO_USER=
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1000
VMWARE_KEEP_CONFIG=yes
sh: 0: cannot open ./VMware-Horizon-Client-5.4.1-15988340.arch.bundle: No such file
@-OMN:~$
```

Then, I navigate to bin folder and run `vmware-uninstall` this is the output I got:

```
@-OMN:/bin$ vmware-uninstall
You have gotten this message because you are either downgrading VMware
Workstation, Player, or VIX, or because you attempted to run either
vmware-uninstall or vmware-uninstall-vix.

If you are downgrading, please uninstall all newer versions first, then
install again.

The vmware-uninstall* scripts have been deprecated.  Instead, please use
the vmware-installer.

Long form:
      vmware-installer --uninstall-product PRODUCT
Short form:
      vmware-installer -u PRODUCT

Where PRODUCT is one of vmware-workstation, vmware-player, or vmware-vix.

For a list of which products are installed, you may run:
      vmware-installer --list-products
or:
      vmware-installer -l
```

Lastly, I ran `vmware-installer -l`, this is the output I got:

```
@-OMN:/bin$ vmware-installer -l

Product Name         Product Version     
==================== ====================
vmware-workstation   16.1.2.17966106
```

This is build and version I currently have installed on Ubuntu 21.04 below:

[image]

Comment: What didn't or did work exactly? Your questions is very confusing.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i tried the links i provided in the article and it didnt work. When i searched in my ' bin' folder and ran 'vmware-installer -l' command to see if my system recognize Horizon client is installed. Ubuntu does not recognize Horizon Client is installed. I am trying to get Horizon Client removed

Comment: Did you adjusted the command to fit the specific version you installed? Were there any error messages? What happened exactly? This are the details missing in your question. Saying "didn't work" isn't useful. Please edit and post the exact commands used and the output in full in code tags.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i will adjust the question

Answer (score 0):

I checked out this post:

[vmware horizon client not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237445/vmware-horizon-client-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

I downloaded the VMware Horizon Client 2006 bundle file from this website:

https://customerconnect.vmware.com/en/downloads/details?downloadGroup=CART21FQ2_LIN64_800&productId=1027&rPId=48990#product_downloads

When I ran the command `sudo sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-2006-8.0.0-16522670.x64.bundle`
This is the output after disclaimer:

```
   The product is ready to be installed:
        Media Optimization for Microsoft Teams
        USB Redirection
        SerialPort Redirection
        Scanner Redirection
        Multimedia Redirection (MMR)
        VMware Integrated Printing
        Smart Card
        HTML5 Multimedia Redirection (HTML5MMR)
        VMware Horizon(R) Virtualization Pack for Skype for Business
        Real-Time Audio-Video
        PCoIP
        Horizon Client
        Client Drive Redirection
    Press Enter to begin installation or Ctrl-C to cancel.
    
    Uninstalling VMware Horizon Scanner Redirection 5.4.1All installation information is about to be removed. Do you wish to
    keep your installation configuration file? [yes]: no

Uninstalling VMware Horizon Scanner Redirection 5.4.1
```

Application been uninstalled.